# Laravel application on docker - ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I tried to run my application on Docker. I built the image using `docker-compose build --no-cache`, and it worked. After that, I used `docker-compose up`. In Docker Desktop, I can see that the database and application are working. Yes, I can connect to the database. However, when I go to `localhost:80`, I get `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.

After `docker-compose up`, I have this log:

```
2023-07-29 17:52:50 npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
2023-07-29 17:52:50 (!) Could not auto-determine entry point from rollupOptions or html files and there are no explicit optimizeDeps.include patterns. Skipping dependency pre-bundling.
2023-07-29 17:59:58 (!) Could not auto-determine entry point from rollupOptions or html files and there are no explicit optimizeDeps.include patterns. Skipping dependency pre-bundling.
2023-07-29 17:52:45 
2023-07-29 17:52:45 added 1 package in 446ms
2023-07-29 17:52:45   installing : node-v18.16.1
2023-07-29 17:52:45        mkdir : /usr/local/n/versions/node/18.16.1
2023-07-29 17:52:45        fetch : https://nodejs.org/dist/v18.16.1/node-v18.16.1-linux-x64.tar.xz
2023-07-29 17:52:47      copying : node/18.16.1
2023-07-29 17:52:48    installed : v18.16.1 (with npm 9.5.1)
2023-07-29 17:52:48 
2023-07-29 17:52:48 Note: the node command changed location and the old location may be remembered in your current shell.
2023-07-29 17:52:48          old : /usr/bin/node
2023-07-29 17:52:48          new : /usr/local/bin/node
2023-07-29 17:52:48 If "node --version" shows the old version then start a new shell, or reset the location hash with:
2023-07-29 17:52:48 hash -r  (for bash, zsh, ash, dash, and ksh)
2023-07-29 17:52:48 rehash   (for csh and tcsh)
2023-07-29 17:52:50 
2023-07-29 17:52:50 added 40 packages, and audited 41 packages in 2s
2023-07-29 17:52:50 
2023-07-29 17:52:50 10 packages are looking for funding
2023-07-29 17:52:50   run `npm fund` for details
2023-07-29 17:52:50 
2023-07-29 17:52:50 1 low severity vulnerability
2023-07-29 17:52:50 
2023-07-29 17:52:50 To address all issues, run:
2023-07-29 17:52:50   npm audit fix
2023-07-29 17:52:50 
2023-07-29 17:52:50 Run `npm audit` for details.
2023-07-29 17:52:50 
2023-07-29 17:52:50 > prod
2023-07-29 17:52:50 > vite production
2023-07-29 17:52:50 
2023-07-29 17:52:50 
2023-07-29 17:52:50   VITE v4.4.5  ready in 177 ms
2023-07-29 17:52:50 
2023-07-29 17:52:50   ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
2023-07-29 17:52:50   ➜  Network: use --host to expose
2023-07-29 17:59:55 
2023-07-29 17:59:55 changed 1 package in 342ms
2023-07-29 17:59:55      copying : node/18.16.1
2023-07-29 17:59:56    installed : v18.16.1 (with npm 9.5.1)
2023-07-29 17:59:57 
2023-07-29 17:59:57 up to date, audited 41 packages in 1s
2023-07-29 17:59:57 
2023-07-29 17:59:57 10 packages are looking for funding
2023-07-29 17:59:57   run `npm fund` for details
2023-07-29 17:59:57 
2023-07-29 17:59:57 1 low severity vulnerability
2023-07-29 17:59:57 
2023-07-29 17:59:57 To address all issues, run:
2023-07-29 17:59:57   npm audit fix
2023-07-29 17:59:57 
2023-07-29 17:59:57 Run `npm audit` for details.
2023-07-29 17:59:58 
2023-07-29 17:59:58 > prod
2023-07-29 17:59:58 > vite production
2023-07-29 17:59:58 
2023-07-29 17:59:58 
2023-07-29 17:59:58   VITE v4.4.5  ready in 184 ms
2023-07-29 17:59:58 
2023-07-29 17:59:58   ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
2023-07-29 17:59:58   ➜  Network: use --host to expose
```

##### `Dockerfile`

```
FROM php:8.2-apache

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
    nodejs \
    npm \
    curl \
    zip \
    unzip \
  && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY . .
COPY ./docker/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
COPY --from=composer:2.5.8 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN a2enmod rewrite

ENV PORT=80
ENTRYPOINT ["docker/entrypoint.sh"]
```

##### `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
    laravel:
        container_name: shop-yt
        build:
            context: .
        ports:
            - 80:80
        volumes:
            - shop-yt-volume:/var/www/html/storage
        networks:
            - shop-yt-network

    database:
        container_name: shop-yt-db
        image: mariadb:latest
        ports:
            - ${DB_PORT}:3306
        environment:
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_DATABASE}
            - MYSQL_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
        volumes:
            - shop-yt-db-volume:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
            - shop-yt-network

volumes:
    shop-yt-volume:
        driver: local
    shop-yt-db-volume:
        driver: local

networks:
    shop-yt-network:
        driver: bridge
```

##### `entrypoint.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

npm install -g n
n 18.16.1
npm install
npm run prod

composer install --no-interaction --no-progress

php artisan key:generate
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
#php artisan serve --port=$PORT --host=0.0.0.0

cd public && ln -sf ../storage/app/public/ storage

chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html

exec docker-php-entrypoint apache2-foreground
```

##### `vhost.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/public"
    <Directory /var/www/html/public>
       Options FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend you switch to [`Laravel Sail`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sail), it is already a mature Docker for Laravel (from Laravel itself), you will have fewer issues. Your setup is not wrong, but there are things I would do differently, for example, using `nginx` in a separate container than Laravel, put the whole volume (do not `COPY . .` but share the whole folder with the Laravel's container) and more stuff